# Storing upper/lower half of correlation matrix

Tags: python, matrix

What is the **most { (1) memory efficient (2) time efficient (3) easy-to-access* } way** to store the upper/lower half of the correlation matrix to a file in **python** ?
(By "easy-to-access" I mean- to be able to read from the file and plot the correlation matrix using matplotlib/seaborn)
Example, for a correlation matrix below:

```
    C1   C2   C3   C4
C1  1.0  0.6  0.7  0.5  
C2  0.6  1.0  0.4  0.9  
C3  0.7  0.4  1.0  0.3
C4  0.5  0.9  0.3  1.0
```

I want to store the below numbers to a file.

```
    C2   C3   C4
C1  0.6  0.7  0.5
C2       0.4  0.9
C3            0.3
```

OR

```
    C1   C2   C3  
C2  0.6
C3  0.7  0.4
C4  0.5  0.9  0.3
```

(I thought of storing it as a csv/tsv file but it will still eat up memory for blank characters which will be there for the other half of the matrix.)

Comment: So your matrix is a `list` or  `numpy array` ?

Comment: Use the second representation. You don't need the blanks in than case.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar its in a list of lists form but can be converted to np-array.

Comment: @HariUserX sorry there is a edit, I want to store column names also along with values.

Comment: Numpy has `tri` and `triu` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html

Answer (score 2):

You need somthing like this:

```
matrix = np.array([[1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.5],
          [0.6, 1, 0.4, 0.9],
          [0.7, 0.4, 1, 0.3],
          [0.5, 0.9, 0.3, 1]])

ut = np.triu(matrix, k=1)
lt = np.tril(matrix, k=-1)

ut = np.where(ut==0, np.nan, ut)
lt = np.where(lt==0, np.nan, lt)

np.savetxt("upper.csv", ut, delimiter=",")
np.savetxt("lower.csv", lt, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Yeah, saving it as a CSV was an option for me already. The purpose of this question is to ask how to prevent the unnecessary zeroes in the matrix.

Comment: it should be `np.savetxt`

Comment: @flyingDope I have converted 0's into nans. Writing it as `.txt` might help

Comment: Ohh, yes NANs did reduce the size of the csv file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the second representation. Its just the transpose of the first and you don't need to store any blank characters for the other half. If blanks characters is your concern, write a custom file writer/reader for your matrix.

Example:

```py
mat = []

mat.append(["C1", "C2", "C3"])
mat.append(["C2", 0.6])
mat.append(["C3", 0.7, 0.4])
mat.append(["C4", 0.5, 0.9, 0.3])

print(mat)

with open("correlation.txt", "w") as _file:
    for row in mat:
        _file.write("\t".join(str(val) for val in row))
        _file.write("\n") # you will not have blank characters

with open("correlation.txt", "r") as _file:
    for line in _file.readlines():
        print(len(line.split()))
```

Result:

> [['C1', 'C2', 'C3'], ['C2', 0.6], ['C3', 0.7, 0.4], ['C4', 0.5, 0.9, 0.3]]
>   3
>   2
>   3
>   4