# How to not show repeated values in a heatmap in plotly express (px.imshow)?

Tags: matrix, plotly, heatmap, correlation

I'm trying to plot a matrix using a heatmap chart but I would like to avoid repeated values;

When using seaborn we can set a "mask" to avoid showing all values, but I can't find the equivalent on Plotly / Plotly Express;

I would like to see something like:
[image]

But at this moment, it is the below format:

[image]

Below is an MWE example of my data structure... Any reference or help to do this will be very welcome

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

heatmap_data=pd.DataFrame(
    {'user1': {'user1': 1,
               'user2': 0.5267109866774764,
               'user3': 0.905914413030722},
    'user2': {'user1': 0.5267109866774764,
              'user2': 1,
              'user3': 0.5160264783692895},
    'user3': {'user1': 0.905914413030722,
              'user2': 0.5160264783692895,
              'user3': 1}
    })
fig = px.imshow(heatmap_data,  zmin=0, zmax=1, 
                text_auto=True, 
                color_continuous_scale="Plasma")
fig
```

Answer (score 2):

The plotly heatmap does not implement the functionality you would expect. Also, matrix diagrams such as scatter plots have the ability to hide the top half. See this for [examples](https://plotly.com/python/splom/#splom-of-the-iris-data-set). So I take advantage of the fact that null values are not displayed and replace unwanted data with null values in the original data. The default style then remains, so we change the theme and hide the axis lines. Finally, the height of the color bar is adjusted.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

heatmap_data=pd.DataFrame(
    {'user1': {'user1': 1,
               'user2': 0.5267109866774764,
               'user3': 0.905914413030722},
    'user2': {'user1': 0.5267109866774764,
              'user2': 1,
              'user3': 0.5160264783692895},
    'user3': {'user1': 0.905914413030722,
              'user2': 0.5160264783692895,
              'user3': 1}
    })

heatmap_data.loc['user1','user2']=None
heatmap_data.loc['user1','user3']=None
heatmap_data.loc['user2','user3']=None

fig = px.imshow(heatmap_data,
                zmin=0,
                zmax=1,
                text_auto=True, 
                color_continuous_scale="Plasma",
                template='simple_white'
               )
fig.update_xaxes(showline=False)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=False)
fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=400, coloraxis=dict(colorbar=dict(len=0.8)))
fig
```

[image]

Comment: But, how could I do this in a programmatic way? My table can have up to 9 users, so I can't hardcode it =/

Comment: I don't know what the original data for your heatmap looks like, but I think it can be handled programmatically with the excellent answers in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254507/storing-upper-lower-half-of-correlation-matrix).

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your answer... I have fixed the problem by looping through all columns and indexes and enumerating them... So, when the column_n is lower than the index_n I will fill in the values, otherwise, I will set the value as None; Doing it this way, it worked; Anyway, thank you very much for your support and kindness